# How to write $routeProvider.whenLoggedIn function in common place for all modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have a `config` function in each module file like below

in `app.js`

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
       function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
 }]);
```

in `home.js`

```
config(['$routeProvider','ChartJsProvider', 
       function ($routeProvider,ChartJsProvider) {
          $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          });   
}])
```

now I want to write a `$routeProvider.whenLoggedIn` function like

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
   function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

     $routeProvider.whenLoggedIn=function(){
        console.log('Do something');
     }

     $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

}]);
```

when I wrote code like code below

```
     $routeProvider.whenLoggedIn('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'home/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      });
```

I want to call the function `whenLoggedIn`. Please let me know how to write `whenLoggedIn` function in common place instead writing this function in every module `config` function

Comment: You can use run block to inject a common function across your angular module.

Answer (score 0):

You   need to add `$stateProvider` in app.config

```
 .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/account/login');

$stateProvider

    .state('account', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/account',
        cache: false,
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    })
  //login
  .state('account.login', {
    url: '/login',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/Account/login.html',
  })

      //forgot password
  .state('account.forgotpassword', {
    url: '/forgotpassword',
    controller: 'ForgotPswdCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/Account/forgotpassword.html',
  })
}])
```